# How to replace entire string contained in a text file to new line using java?

Tags: java, regex

My text file contains data data as follows:

```
|------------------+------+-------------+------------------
  A regular expression can be a single-character pattern or multiple-character  pattern.
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

So I want to replace |------------------+------+-------------+------------------  and ---------------------------------------------------   using a regular expression e.g replace a complete string which contains 0 or more '-' character. Thank you.

Currently I'm using :
                                                                              line=line.replace("|------------------+------+-------------+------------------","\n");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can regex in `replaceAll` like this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("[|+-]+", "\n");
```

Comment: thanks it does works. But my text file contains +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  lines which is not replaced. Any suggestions?